# Java Changing image color

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class Transparency {
  public static Image makeColorTransparent(Image im, final Color color) {
ImageFilter filter = new RGBImageFilter() {
  public int markerRGB = color.getRGB() | 0xFF000000;

  public final int filterRGB(int x, int y, int rgb) {
    if ( ( rgb | 0xFF000000 ) == markerRGB ) {
      return 0x00FFFFFF & rgb;
      }
    else {
      return rgb;
      }
    }
  }; 

ImageProducer ip = new FilteredImageSource(im.getSource(), filter);
return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(ip);
}
}

GifModifiedWithTransparentBackground = 
   Transparency.makeColorTransparent
    (GifOriginalWithWithBlueBackground, new Color(0).blue);
  }
```

I found this example to change a background to transparent, but I can't find the place where it is actually set to transparent. Instead of having it transparent I want to change it to another color but I can't because I don't know where it sets it to transparent. Can somebody tell me where it is being set to transparent?

Comment: `return 0x00FFFFFF & rgb;`. That's the same color, with the alpha set to zero.

Comment: Color values are stored as `0xAARRGGBB`. If you want a different alpha, replace the alpha part (the `00`) with the value you want (between `00` and `FF`).

Comment: so if i change it it will change the color that is replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the format `0xAARRGGBB` where `AA` is the alpha (transparency), `RR` is the red, `GG` is the green, and `BB` is the blue component. This is hexadecimal, so the values range from 00 to FF (255).

Your question is about the replacement of the alpha value. This line:

`public int markerRGB = 0xFF000000;`

If you consider a value like `0xFF000000` (black), `AND` will return `0x00000000` which is zero alpha value of black, a transparent color. Similarly you will get transparent alpha values which makes certain points of your image transparent after you assign a value into `markerRGB`.